# SQLAlchemy - how can I commit some INSERTs immediately within a transaction?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My (CLI) app uses SQLAlchemy 1.3. One of the jobs it has to perform is to query for a large number of records (>300k), then do some calculations on those and insert new records based on the results of the processing.
The app writes its activites into a log table as well, so I can see what it is currently doing during that long running job. I have various piplines (tasks), so there is a "pipelines" table with a 1:many relationship to a "log_messages" table.

I am using the ORM style, omitting the model classes here. I think it's not relevant but let me know if I should add more details.

So the general flow is something like this:

```
def perform_task():
    with session_scope() as session:
        # get a pipeline record for our log messages to link to
        pipeline = session.query(Pipelines).filter(Pipelines.name=='some_name')

        # log the start of the work
        pipeline.append(LogMessage( text="started work")

        # query the records we are working on (>300k) 
        job_input_all = session.query(SomeModel).filter(SomeModel.is_of_interest = True ).all()
        for job_input in job_input_all():
            job_input.append(SomeOtherModel( something_calculated = _do_calculation(job_input, pipeline)))
        
        pipeline.append(LogMessage( text="finished work")        
            
            
def _do_calculation( job_input, pipeline ):
    # of course this isn't the real calcualtion, just illsutrating that "something happens here"
    # the real stuff is complex and takes a lot of time to compute
    # and we need to write log messages from time to time
    calculated_value = job_input.value * 1000
    if calculated_value > 100000:
        pipeline.append(LogMessage( text=f'input value {job_input.value} resulted in bad output {calculated_value}'))
```

If I do it that way, none of the log messages will appear until the session scope ends, which commits everything. As this job takes a long time, it is important that I get the logs updated in real time so I can see what is going on. How would I do this?
If I commit after each pipeline log message is created, I will invalidate (and force to re-query) the row result objects in job_input_all, which would be bad. Even more problematic: I can't commit logs in _do_calculation() because I don't want to commit all the calculated stuff yet.

I have worked with ORMs in other languages before but I am new to SQLA (and Python for that matter) so I'm probably missing something fundamental here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I might go with logging in two places: I will keep logs in the DB because it allows me to link log messages to records in various tables, which I am doing at the moment. But in addition, I will write the same log message to to file with the "logger" package. that way, I have my immediate feedback of what the app is doing in real time and I get use log messages in queries later. Will be quite easy to add to the real app because writing of log messages is already handled by a method in a class that does all the DB interactions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to not write logs in this manner. If you instead wrote logs to an ELK (Elasticsearch/Logstash/Kibana) stack you could make it independent of your session and have all the nice inbuilt log-related features that Kibana gives you out of the box, in an easy to use web-GUI.

Comment: thanks for making me aware of this. I don't think it will be an option for me for various reasons though. Also: If I would write logs somewhere else, I would loose the ability to link log entries with other records in the app, which I need.

Comment: Your other option is to create your session as Session = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False) This will stop invalidating your row objects on commit. The downside is this may effect your code in unexpected ways.

Comment: sounds like something I should check out. The larger resultset of rows that go into the computationally heavy step will never be updated in the DB, so not expiring them seems like a good option

Comment: I think I might go with logging in two places: I will keep logs in the DB because it allows me to link log messages to records in various tables, which I am doing at the moment. But in addition, I will write the same log message to to file with the "logger" package. that way, I have my immediate feedback of what the app is doing in real time and I get use log messages in queries later. Will be quite easy to add to the real app because writing of log messages is already handled by a method in a class that does all the DB interactions anyway.